# Writing insert statements with knex.js on Node API confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I've a problem I can't really seem to wrap my head around. It's very specific to the Knex.JS implementation and I'm sure has nothing to do with PostgreSQL.

The following implementation works. When inserting a moderate amount (~500 statements). On larger amounts this fails due to other reasons. Regardless, the following will not work for my use case, I need something like the next section.

```
import knex = require("knex");
(function (items) {
  let db = knex.table("items");

  db.truncate();

  let foo = [];
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    foo.push({
       id : item.id,
       item_data : JSON.stringify(item)
    });
  });

  db.insert(foo).then(function () { /*..*/ });

}(items))
```

But the following doesn't:

```
import knex = require("knex");
(function (items) {
  let db = knex.table("items");

  db.truncate();

  let foo = [];
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    db.then(function() {
        return db.insert(foo).into("items");
    });
  });

  db.then(function () { console.log("Done"); });

}(items))
```

What doesn't work is this:

- An inconsistent amount of rows are inserted. In some implementations it's a lot MORE than I have items (?!)
- I get a lot of duplicate key errors in this implementation, since I have a unique constraint

Additional information:

- The set contains no duplicate keys
- I'm using PostgreSQL as backend

The question is mostly how to implement the desired behaviour. The ideal situation deals in chunks of say 500 "items". I've already posted a question with the project (https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/826) but I'm hoping some people of the Knex.JS community are more active here on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is correct (promise chaining), however since you're using Knex it ships with Bluebird which already provides a utility method for this:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird"); // also used internally by Knex so free to require

Promise.each(items, db.insert.bind(db));
```

Would do the same thing as:

```
items.forEach(function(item) {
  chain = chain.then(function () {
     return db.insert(item);
  });
});
```

Comment: There are more examples for this at the knex docs here: http://knexjs.org/#Interfaces-Promises

Comment: Excellent example. I'm new to the famous Bluebird library and in all honesty I didn't read your solution from the Knex examples. So thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. I'm not entirely convinced the problem is the fault of Knex.js or if it's my own lack of experiences with Promises in general.

I found inspiration in the work done by Tim Griesser here: https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/batch-insert/lib/util/batch-insert.js

Basically what he did is to add chunks to a promise chain. Perhaps this can be done directly on the Knex library, but for readability I've kept it separate.

```
import knex = require("knex");
(function (items) {
  let db = knex.table("items");

  // This is the basic operation to add a promise to the chain.
  chain = chain.then(function() { return db.truncate(); });

  let foo = [];
  items.forEach(function(item) {

    // Add db.insert() promises to our promise chain
    // This can easily be changed to include chunks and/or streams
    chain = chain.then(function () {
        return db.insert(item);
    });
  });

  // Start resolving the promises once our db.then() is invoked.
  return db.then(function(){
    return chain.then();
  });

}(items));
```

Comment: Your `chain.then()` function doesn't actually do anything. Promises work by using return values - did you mean to `return chain`?

Comment: Yes, I did. I've updated the answer. My actual implementation actually returns (-: